I'm seeking advice on announcing another vulnerability. How should I proceed?
We know that the vulnerability in RSA encryption arises when the difference between the two prime numbers is too small. For RSA, the attacker targets factorizing $n=p\times q$. If the difference $p−q<2\times n^{1/4}$, then RSA encryption becomes susceptible to "Fermat Factorization" attacks."
I'm seeking advice on announcing another vulnerability. How should I proceed?

Similar question.

First, be completely sure that is indeed a new vulnerability. Textbook RSA is already known to be quite vulnerable to different attacks, such as the one mentioned. You can ensure the novelty of your vulnerability if you perform a systematic literature review on the topic. When you are positive it is a new vulnerability then you have some options:

Contact a relevant cryptographer to discuss your findings. If they are good she/he can help you with the next step.
Write and publish a paper. Do not worry, you can publish it as a pre-print on a platform like IACR. If your discovery is worth it, even the pre-print will be read and noticed by the community.
Use Researchgate or Linkedin to divulge your findings.


Your response was excellent, particularly the mention of the IACR.

Thank you. I have learned something during the last years in crypto research. I genuinely believe such a claim (the question) is huge, anyone must proceed with caution.

Since cryptography is a weapon of war, it would make sense for a patriot to divulge any vulnerabilities to your local (GCHQ/NSA)  intelligence services.
Or, you  can   cash in whilst claiming to  support  the correct form of  democracy. Decent exploits sell for $100,000s and the payments can be washed clean.
